# Arduino Serial Communication possible with IDE 1.8.5 but not with IDE 1.8.13

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, arduino-nano, serial-data, arduino-nano-33-iot

I have the following problem: I am working with an Arduino Nano 33 IoT and a second serial interface via sercom0. The code is just taken from this tutorial:

http://www.getmicros.net/serial-communication-on-the-arduino-nano-iot.php

In loop, I just print the input from my serial connection to the standard serial connection. The input comes from a ozon sensor that sends data packages every single second.

Now when I program the arduino with my Laptop, my IDE version being 1.8.5, it works well, but when I use my PC with a newer version (IDE 1.8.13), it doesn't work any more. The code is the same, the cable and the arduino are the same, the only difference is the PC. But when I try to use an hyperterminal to print the data packages recieved from the sensor, both the Laptop and the PC receive the correct packages. Somehow, the Arduino or the difference in IDE versions causes the communication to fail....

Does anyone have experience with this error?

Comment: "this error" Are you getting an actual error message?  If so, what is it?

Comment: If you program on your laptop then plug into your PC does it work? How about the other way around?

Comment: Serial1 is there for pins labeled RX/TX. the boards package version is independent from IDE version so IDE version doesn't give any useful information here.

Comment: I am not getting an error message since for both cases, data is being revied by the arduino. The problem is that the data is different when I use the serial interface on my PC.

No, sadly programming it on my Laptop and then plugging it into my PC does not work...

I don't really understand what you mean, Serial1 is not being used. I use the normal Serial for sending the data to the PC or Laptop and the sercom0 interface for reading in the sensor values.